# Admin moderates ALL comments (including post author)

Tags: posts, admin, comments, moderation

I have comments enabled on my custom post type page, which works well but I need the admin to moderate all comments before they are published.

At the moment the post author whose level is 'contributor' is able to post comments without being moderated.

I can't find any way to do this currently, nor can I find any plugins.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try this: Capability Manager http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/capsman/ and also read (if you have't already done so) the Wordpress roles and capabilities docs: http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities

Answer (score -1):

Check this option

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/comment-moderation-issue-need-help

The relevant code from that thread is:

```
add_filter('pre_comment_approved', 'xko_pre_comment_approved', null, 2);

function xko_pre_comment_approved($approved, $commentdata)
{
    $approved = 0;
    return $approved;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to WordPress Answers! [An answer should be more than just a link to an external site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion). Please add a solution.